# Display JavaScript Object in HTML

Tags: javascript, object, dom

I have a object that looks like this:

```
var grocery_list = {
  "Banana": { category: "produce", price: 5.99 },
  "Chocolate": { category: "candy", price: 2.75 },
  "Wheat Bread": { category: "grains and breads", price: 2.99 }
}
```

And I want to be able to display each item in the object in HTML like this:

```
<div id="grocery_item" class="container">
    <div class="item">Item Here</div>
    <div class="category">Category Here</div>
    <div class="price">Price Here</div>
</div>
```

I know how to loop through an Object in JS, but I'm not sure how to display those items in the DOM. I believe I could use the jQuery append function but I'm not sure how.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: mustache (or some other templater) is what you need https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Comment: @dandavis I would love to learn how to write it out with JS or jQuery first.

Comment: Objects (officially) have no order. It would be better to make grocery_list an array of objects and add a name property to those objects with `Banana` and `Chocolate` etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how you can do it using jQuery (as you mention you'd like to use jQuery first). But it's not the best way how to it. If you're open to learn better methods then check some of the MV* frameworks (AngularJS, Ember etc.). Anyway, here is just an example:

```
var grocery_list = {
  "Banana": { category: "produce", price: 5.99 },
  "Chocolate": { category: "candy", price: 2.75 },
  "Wheat Bread": { category: "grains and breads", price: 2.99 }
}

var wrapper = $('#wrapper'), container;
for (var key in grocery_list){
    container = $('<div id="grocery_item" class="container"></div>');
    wrapper.append(container);
    container.append('<div class="item">' + key +'</div>');
    container.append('<div class="category">' + grocery_list[key].category +'</div>');
    container.append('<div class="price">' + grocery_list[key].price +'</div>');
}
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5jhgbg9w/

*EDIT: Please, take this really as an example (which is OK since you're learning). As others pointed out - it's not the best method. Try to combine other examples, particularly the ones which do not compose HTML as a string. For easy tasks like this it's straightforward but the more code you would add, the messier the code becomes. I believe your "learning evolution" would get you there anyway :-) Cheers everyone*

**EDIT (2021):** A lot of years have gone by since I answered this question. What about some more modern examples, just for fun? Without jQuery, just ES6:

```js
const grocery_list = {
  "Banana": { category: "produce", price: 5.99 },
  "Chocolate": { category: "candy", price: 2.75 },
  "Wheat Bread": { category: "grains and breads", price: 2.99 }
};

// since "grocery_list" is an object (not an array) we have do Object.keys()
const generatedHtml = Object.keys(grocery_list).reduce((accum, currKey) => accum +
  `<div class="grocery_item">
    <div class="item">${currKey}</div>
    <div class="category">${grocery_list[currKey].category}</div>
    <div class="price">${grocery_list[currKey].price}</div>
  </div>`, '');

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = generatedHtml;
```

```css
.grocery_item{
  padding: 5px;
}
.grocery_item:not(:last-child){
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: You can still use templating without using other frameworks. A basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/5jhgbg9w/1/ . Your version is also open for undesired html injection.

Comment: Awesome...thank you @ivan.sivak !

How can I get that display to work on the same page where I have a form taking that data? JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kemr26e0/

Comment: @theartofbeing is this a school assignment? It's not the best code ever but imho you can learn to improve it by yourself from here on: http://jsfiddle.net/e74443zc/

Comment: @René It is a school project...we're just learning how to integrate JS into the DOM.

Comment: theartofbeing: you need to just put that code on your page where you have data. Try to combine our examples. René's version is better btw :) thanks René

Comment: @René That did the trick...thank you a ton.

ivan.sivak thank you a ton as well. Sometimes I just need to see how someone else does it so I can understand it.

Comment: @theartofbeing If it's a school project, you probably have a teacher ;-) Having half the work done for you on stackoverflow is not the way to go. Certainly not how most of us learned.

Comment: @René - One last question if you're still around. Now I want to be able to remove an item from that list. Trying it here: http://jsfiddle.net/e74443zc/1/ 

But not working

Comment: @theartofbeing: if you need removal by item name, look here: http://jsfiddle.net/e74443zc/3/ basically I added a key that joins item in array and on DOM level and function that finds the item by name and removes from grocery array and from HTML.

Comment: @ivan.sivak Man, this seems so damn complicated. I'm used to Ruby and it's just such a mess to read what's going on. You have to search for the item because it's in an array, correct?

Are there much simpler ways to write what we're doing here?

Comment: @theartofbeing: the thing is that you need to know which grocery_list item represents what DIV container. You need to remove the grocery_list item, so you need to remove it from array but from HTML as well. That's why I added a key to grocery_list item which is then rendered as attribute on DIV container. That's what joins them. The remove function then needs to find this key based on provided name (it is my understanding that you'd like to remove item  by name). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can create HTML elements with jQuery: `$('<div>', {attr1: value, attr2: value});` This returns a new jQuery object so you can use it like jQuery element.

The jQuery.text() method: `$('div').text('some text')` This method is recommended if you putting just text inside the element. It will escape all special characters like `'<'`. Instead it puts `&lt`. This avoiding XSS attacks unlike jQuery.html() method.
You can look Security Considerations at [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/#entry-longdesc) about .html method.

```
// Create a div element with jQuery which will hold all items.
var $tree = $('<div>', {id: 'items-tree'});
//Loop all items and create elements for each
for (var key in grocery_list) {
  var $gItem = $('<div>', {
    id: 'grocery_item',
    class: 'container'
  });

  var $item = $('<div>', {
    class: 'item'
  }).text(key);
  $gItem.append($item);

  var $category = $('<div>', {
    class: 'category'
  }).text(grocery_list[key].category);
  $gItem.append($category);

  var $price = $('<div>', {
    class: 'price'
  }).text(grocery_list[key].price);
  $gItem.append($price);

  $tree.append($gItem);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnonzcmv/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It's old but you can try package [html-stringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-stringify). As its introduction: "Converts Javascript Objects or Arrays to pretty HTML string for rendering in a browser."

Answer (score 0):

The parent div `<div id="grocery_item" class="container">` will be repeated for the no. of items in the grocery list.
The "id" of this parent div will be generated randomly for example item @index 0 will be "grocery_item0"

For each loop item create the parent div's first, then start appending the details to the parent div's using (another loop).
Below will be sample jquery,

$( ".grocery_item0" ).append( "" );

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I've never implemented that before so I'm not sure how to code it so it sends to the div element...

Answer (score 0):

I will pass by the fact that your list definition is not exactly the best and I say this:

Using jQuery you could do that:

```
<script>
var _parent = $(".container").parent();
_parent.empty();

var _html;
$.each(grocery_list,function(prop, val){
    _html = "<div id=\"grocery_item\" class=\"container\">";
    _html += "<div class=\"item\">"+prop+"</div>";
    _html += "<div class=\"category\">"+val.category+"</div>";
    _html += "<div class=\"price\">"+val.price+"</div>";
    _html += "</div>";

    _parent.append(_html);
});
</script>
```

Note*: It's not recomanded to maanipulate the DOM by creating HTML strings. This is just an fast sample for your school assignment.

Comment: You should not propagate the horrible idea of building HTML as strings.

Comment: Well, as you can see all the solutions are in the same direction and I am the only one who got a -1 That's not fair ...:))

Comment: If you edit your answer it would give down-voters a chance to re-vote.