# Displaying Object properties

Tags: javascript

I want to display the Object properties (Label, Icon, Href) from a randomly chosen object from the array. How should I go about this, This is what I have so far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  var myArray = [{
    label: "Pears",
    icon: "Pears.png",
    href: "./Pears"
  }, {
    label: "Appels",
    icon: "Appels.png",
    href: "./Appels"
  }, {
    label: "Mango",
    icon: "Mango.png",
    href: "./Mango"
  }, ];

  var randomItem1 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem2 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem3 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem4 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    document.getElementById("randomItem1").innerHTML = randomItem1;
    document.getElementById("randomItem2").innerHTML = randomItem2;
    document.getElementById("randomItem3").innerHTML = randomItem3;
    document.getElementById("randomItem4").innerHTML = randomItem4;      

  });
</script>
<p>Random 1</p>
    <div id = "randomItem1"> </div>
    <!--Label value-->
    <!--Icon value-->
    <!--Href value-->
<p>Random 2</p>
    <div id = "randomItem2"> </div>
<p>Random 3</p>
    <div id = "randomItem3"> </div>
<p>Random 4</p>
    <div id = "randomItem4"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display JavaScript Object in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266901/display-javascript-object-in-html)

Comment: `innerHTML = Object.values(randomItem1).join()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use their object key, e.g.

```
randomItem1.label
randomItem1.icon
randomItem1.href
```

Stack snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  var myArray = [{
    label: "Pears",
    icon: "Pears.png",
    href: "./Pears"
  }, {
    label: "Appels",
    icon: "Appels.png",
    href: "./Appels"
  }, {
    label: "Mango",
    icon: "Mango.png",
    href: "./Mango"
  }, ];

  var randomItem1 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem2 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem3 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem4 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    // grabbed all keys in this first assignment to show how-to
    document.getElementById("randomItem1").innerHTML = randomItem1.label + " : " +
                                                       randomItem1.icon + " : " +
                                                       randomItem1.href;

    document.getElementById("randomItem2").innerHTML = randomItem2.label;
    document.getElementById("randomItem3").innerHTML = randomItem3.label;
    document.getElementById("randomItem4").innerHTML = randomItem4.label;      

  });
</script>
<p>Random 1</p>
    <div id = "randomItem1"> </div>
    <!--Label value-->
    <!--Icon value-->
    <!--Href value-->
<p>Random 2</p>
    <div id = "randomItem2"> </div>
<p>Random 3</p>
    <div id = "randomItem3"> </div>
<p>Random 4</p>
    <div id = "randomItem4"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```